# Marking heap shows I have a perpetual retain (ARC enabled). How to fix?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, memory-management, instruments

I log in to the app, then sign out, and make another mark (rinse & repeat). As you can see, my Loginview is getting retained on every instantiation. What's the best/easiest way to find out what the culprit is for keeping the retain count up? I'm just trying to find things in the code and it's taking longer than expected..

Background info:
xcode 4.6
compiled with ARC enabled
this is the only "view" left with a retain problem (I've fixed all the others)

[image: heapshots]

** **EDIT** **

`LoginView` is instantiated with:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [super trackPageViewFor:@"/login"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContentChange:) name:CONTENT_CHANGE object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)removeFromSuperview
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [super removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And when the next view is loaded I'm just letting the prior view fall out of memory (with the help of ARC)

** **EDIT** Object List **

[image: Cycles and Roots]

Comment: That's not enough information to answer your question. Why is a new `LoginView` being created each time? What code is used to *store* the new view (and remove the old view)?

Comment: @trojanfoe I just added an edit which will shed more light on the situation.

Comment: Getting views retained forever in my case is almost always caused by circular references. If you have a reference to your loginview in some object A, and you also keep a reference to A inside loginview, they are locking each other from being dealloc'ed.

Comment: When you look at your object graph in Instruments, what do you see for this object?

Comment: @PeterHosey This is a `cocoa-touch` application. I see that my question tags didn't specify that (which I thought I had done) so I remedied that. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @PeterHosey I should clarify: Per my understanding, the *object graph* is only for OS X. Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: The old, separate Object Graph instrument required garbage collection, which in turn was only for Mac OS X. The new “Cycles and Roots” feature of the Leaks instrument works on both platforms (at least in the Simulator; I don't know whether it works when running on a device).

Comment: @PeterHosey Screenshot attached. Is that the right view?

Comment: No, on both counts. You have the Allocations instrument selected, not the Leaks instrument, and consequently don't have the Leaks instrument's “Cycles and Roots” view selected.

Comment: @PeterHosey I found it. However, the ONLY leaks I get are those from the AV department (nothing to do with my code) My code is causing additional allocations, but not leaks. BTW that big allocation is when I loaded the MPMoviePlayer.